# Results with inaccuracy ( Sphinx)

Tags: php, sphinx

I have a filter where user can set the price range for goods search.

( http://joxi.ru/EA4QDEJfw8xxNr )

When I set the range the results come with inaccuracy both the bottom price (http://joxi.ru/8239D0NuJ744vr) and the top.

When i print my filter i see that all ok.

```
protected function query(DataProvider\Params $params = null)
{
    $this->setSettings();  # sphinx setting

    if ($params) {
        $this->setFilter($params->arFilter);
    } else {
        throw new SphinxException('Empty params');
    }

    return $result = $this->makeQuery();    # execute question and return result
}

private function setFilter(array $filter = null)
{
    $this->sphinx->resetFilters();
    print_r($arValues);
    $this->setSphinxFilterRange($propCode, $arValues['LEFT'], $arValues['RIGHT']);
}
```

> Array ( [LEFT] => 19879 [RIGHT] => 42479 )

Does the sphinx have some inaccuracy?

Comment: There's not a single Sphinx API call in your code. You should provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is `$propCode` set? For that matter how about `$arValues`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the sphinx indexed another database